# Installing new versions of ubuntu alongside /home folder

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, encryption

I am thinking theoretically how ubuntu behaves when you want clean install of OS, but with not-touching /home partition. And what to do when /home is encrypted? 
Can you delete partitions other than /home and make a clean install or what is recommended scenario. 
I got 17.04 because of newest Linux kernel but when 18 LTS will be out I would like to upgrade (probably using clean install). 
Hope it's not duplicate, didn't find exactly same question.

Comment: I suggest you read this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome

Comment: "In the Ubuntu 9.10 setup, the user's encrypted data is located in /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.Private, and the user's configuration data is located in /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs. As such, all of the user's pertinent data is self-contained in /home."   That means that keys are stored in /home. That what I was also looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as you don't delete it (should go without saying) your `/home` partition (encrypted or not) will remain intact when you upgrade your Ubuntu OS to a future release.

The process I follow (which I believe is pretty typical) is to create several partitions: `/`, `/home`, and `swap` (`/boot/efi` is often required as well when using the newer UEFI BIOS).

Maintaining a separate `/home` partition makes it very easy to do an upgrade while allowing your personal data to persist across upgrades.

In my own case, I probably have ~10 years of data in one of my `/home` partitions... and it's survived innumerable upgrades with no problems.